# implement a new directive already compiled template

Tags: angularjs

as we know, the compilation passes once and does not repeat.
What if I have a controller for example

```
<div ng-controller="SomeContr"></div>
```

, then I create the

```
<span>{{ text }}</span>
```

in the controller, and put there this item using the appendChild () method, or even what the realties

```
<div ng-controller="SomeContr">
<span>{{ text }}</span>
</div>
```

question, how can I make it work expression {{ text}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and one of the important things to understand: don't manipulate DOM in controllers, put all your DOM manipulation staff to directives and let controllers to care of model (scope). In order to add some DOM elements dynamically in directive you can use [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile) service (see Usage section) that will do the same job as if you put your string as part of your template:

**HTML**

```
<div app-directive ng-init="text = 'Hello World'"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app',[]).
  directive('appDirective', function($compile) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element) {
        var html = '<span>{{text}}</span>';
        element.append($compile(html)(scope));
      }
    }
  });
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/dYbAMvqEScNITrwjkt13?p=preview